# What is a main thread?

Tags: c, multithreading

What is a main thread in multithreading in a c program?
I need to create m threads and to execute different operations on main thread and on the created m threads. Is the main thread the main function maybe?

Comment: Yes, the main thread is the implicit "thread" you get when your program starts to execute (the main function).

Answer (score 4):

The main thread is the thread on which `main()` is called at program startup. Never end the main thread: on most platforms this ends the process quite rapidly.

There's a reason the alternative to multi-threaded programming is called single-threaded programming, not threadless programming. You always have at least one thread.

While some platforms allow you to create a process without any threads at all, that process isn't going to do anything.